# Issue with Javascript module system I'm trying to make and cant figure out

Tags: scope, closures, javascript

I have an idea I really like for a module system I'm trying to create for one of my projects, the problem is I cant seem to figure it out. The idea is pretty simple, nothing complicated, and very straightforward but I guess I'm missing something as I have spent hours on end trying stuff.

Essentially all I'm wanting to do is have 4 variables, public, protected, package, and private inside a module along with 3 functions augment, extend, and submodule.

The idea is that each module is an anonymous function that saves a public interface to a window variable and have everything else unaccessible. That is, anything in the public variable and the 3 functions are the only public interface.

Ideally, with this setup, you can directly augment any module with the augment function, extend the module as a parent/child relationship with the extend function, and create a submodule on that module with the submodule function. The variables will be accessible to depending on the variable and method chosen for example package will be accessible to all submodules and extensions while protected will not be accessible from a submodule.

This should form a chain as well where each submodule down or each extension can access its parent data and have room to add its own. I should also note that the intention is not like a class where each instance has its own copy of all the variables, rather, theres just one variable pool in each module and their linked to one another depending on actions taken.

What I have below is what I've come up with so far but its not quite right and doesnt fit quite well as it leans to a more class like setup and really doesnt work anything like how I wanted it as described above but should give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

Any help is greatly appreciated, code ans jsfiddle link below

https://jsfiddle.net/0ghbxdpo/

```
function Module()
{
    // Accessible to everything
    this._public = {};

    // Accessible to all extensions and submodules
    this._package = {};

    // Accessible only to extensions of the same module
    this._protected = {};

    // Accessible only to augmentations
    this._private = {};
}

// Augments this module and returns the newly augmented module, using
// the return value isn't nesasary as the actual module would have successfully
// been augmented
// Access to all properties
Module.prototype.augment = function augment(augmentation)
{
    return augmentation({
        _public: this._public,
        _package: this._package,
        _protected: this._protected,
        _private: this._private
        });
}

// Create a new module with this one as its parent
// Access to all but this modules private variables
Module.prototype.extend = function extend(extension)
{
    var obj = new Module();

    obj._public._parent = this._public;
    obj._package._parent = this._package;
    obj._protected._parent = this._protected;

    // Execute the extension module under the context of a new module
    // with all but the private variables as its parents
    return extension.call(obj);
}

// Create a new module and assign it to one of the 4 scope variables, public by default
// Access only to public and package modules
Module.prototype.submodule = function submodule(moduleName, module, scope)
{
    var obj = new Module();

    obj._public._parent = this._public;
    obj._package._parent = this._package;

    // Run the submodule code under the context of the new module
    var tmp = module.call(obj);

    // Then assign it to the correct scope variables
    if(scope === "protected")
        return this._protected[moduleName] = tmp;
    else if(scope === "package")
        return this._package[moduleName] = tmp;
    else if(scope === "private")
        return this._private[moduleName] = tmp;
    else
        return this._public[moduleName] = tmp;
}

// Some test to play around and test it out
// This isnt ideal as theres no way to actually setup anything with the initial module
// Also it reveals all the scopes to the public
window.CoolTest = new Module();

// This fails with an error as "this" points to the wrong object so the whole
// thing is created wrong and fails. You cant use call, apply, or bind from here as
// the public should not have access to anyting but the public variables
// The other scope variables are supposed to be stored internally and automatically
// used to create the submodule without ever exposing them
window.CoolTest.submodule("sub", function()
                       {
                           this._public.hello = "world";
                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and the complete code is in this newly updated jsFiddle link and below it in text to the completed Module system.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ghbxdpo/1/

```
/*
 * Module System
 * This is not intended to be a class emulation nor will it work very well if
 * treated like one.
 *
 * This was created out of desire for sharing properties and functions among
 * different components in a program. One where permissions to all of it is
 * very fine grained and strictly enforced.
 *
 * It was also created out of desire for lazy loading and lazy augmentation. In
 * other words, I want to be able to split a large module into several files
 * and have it just work. I also want each module to be augmentable and
 * extendable still supporting the lazyloading approach and still respecting
 * permissions
 *
 * You create a module by instiating this class, by doing so you will get an
 * empty module. You may also provide a function as parameter to do an initial
 * custom setup, the function will be passed an internal private object which
 * contains the actual class so you can modify where fit. You have access to the
 * entire class. A second parameter may be passed for special cirumstances where
 * you want to access some variable inside the constructor function you provide.
 *
 * After the module is created it returns the public interface, this interface
 * contains only the public variable contents and 3 methods that work on the
 * module. There is intentionally no way to access the full module as it remains
 * closed off tightly to the public.
 *
 * You may perform 3 actions on the module.
 * "_augment" which re-gives you full control over the module and all of its
 *      properties.
 *
 * "_extend" which creates a new module that contins "_parent" links to the
 *      parents public, package, and protected variables. You can directly edit
 *      the parent object or you can add your own properties outside of the
 *      parent. Any changes you make to the parent will be reflected in the
 *      parent while any chnages you make outside of the parent will not be
 *      accessible by it
 *
 * "_submodule" which does what extend does except that instead of leaving out
 *      just the parents private variables, it also leaves out the parents
 *      protected variables. Not only does it do this, but it also ammends
 *      one of its scope variables, public by default, and attaches the modules
 *      public interface to it.
 */
var Module = (function ()
{
    // initFunc is the otpional configuration function
    //      It is passed the internal module object and scopeRef if provided
    // scopeRef is purely used for passing a custom parameter to the init function
    function Module(initFunc, scopeRef)
    {
        // Declare 4 scope variables
        // Augmentation can always modify these values
        this._public = {}; // Accessible to anyone
        this._package = {};     // Accessible to extensions and submodules
        this._protected = {};   // Accessible only to extensions
        this._private = {};     // Not accessible anywhere

        // Scope related reasons
        this._self = this;

        // This is a bit of trickory to allow a public interface entirely closed
        // off from the actual module, it pre-executes and saves the contents
        // to be used later
        // the parameter is the trick in how we access the real module
        this._publicReturn = function publicReturn(self)
        {
            // We prepare the public interface by directly referencing the modules
            // public variable
            var ret = self._public;

            // Then we ammend the interface and the public variable by adding in
            // the 3 methods that can be used to work on the real internal module
            ret._augment = self.augment.bind(self);
            ret._extend = self.extend.bind(self);
            ret._submodule = self.submodule.bind(self);
            return ret;
        }(this);

        // Now that thats all out of the way, we process the given init function
        // if provided
        if (initFunc)
            initFunc(this, scopeRef);

        // And we return only the public interface
        return this._publicReturn;
    }

    // This modifies the module by re-opening up the entire module for any
    // kind of modification, works much the same way as the constructor
    Module.prototype.augment = function (initFunc, scopeRef)
    {
        initFunc(this, scopeRef);
        return this._publicReturn;
    };

    // This creates a brand new module with parent references to this
    // modules public, package, and protected variable scopes
    Module.prototype.extend = function(initFunc, scopeRef)
    {
        // Start with blank module
        var obj = new Module();

        // Augment in the parent references
        obj._augment(function(_obj, _scopeRef)
                   {
                       _obj._public._parent = _scopeRef._public;
                       _obj._package._parent = _scopeRef._package;
                       _obj._protected._parent = _scopeRef._protected;
                   }, this);

        // Allow the user to do augmentation if provided
        if(initFunc)
            obj._augment(initFunc, scopeRef);

        // Return the given public interface
        return obj;
    };

    // This creates a brand new module with parent references to this
    // modules public and package variable scopes. It also ammends the newly
    // made module to one of this modules variable scopes, by default public.
    Module.prototype.submodule = function (moduleName, initFunc, scopeRef, scope)
    {
        // Start with blank module
        var obj = new Module();

        // Augment in the parent references
        obj._augment(function(_obj, _scopeRef)
                   {
                       _obj._public._parent = _scopeRef._public;
                       _obj._package._parent = _scopeRef._package;
                   }, this);

        // Allow the user to do augmentation if provided
        if(initFunc)
            obj._augment(initFunc, scopeRef);

        // Then assign it to the correct scope variables
        if (scope === "protected")
            return this._protected[moduleName] = obj;

        else if (scope === "package")
            return this._package[moduleName] = obj;

        else if (scope === "private")
            return this._private[moduleName] = obj;

        else
            return this._public[moduleName] = obj;
    };

    return Module;
})();
```